# Android: Opening .hprof file In Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, memory, hprof

Im trying to check for memory leaks by using a HPROF File from eclipses DDMS view.

I tried using MAT to read a .hprof saved to disk but got error:

```
Error opening heap dump 'com.myapp.myapp.hprof'. Check the error log for further details.
Error opening heap dump 'com.myapp.myapp.hprof'. Check the error log for further details.
Unknown HPROF Version (JAVA PROFILE 1.0.3) (java.io.IOException)
Unknown HPROF Version (JAVA PROFILE 1.0.3)
```

So i followed a solution in another post on StackOverflow which told me to change the preferences

> Android > DDMS > HPROF Action : View In Eclipse

But that just displays the file as an unreadable text file:
[image: hprof file in eclipse]

Im assuming its supposed to be easier to understand than that so what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I read in other posts about using something called hprov-conv.exe i tried to open that, it flashed a screen then closed (even when opening as an administrator) so i dont know how to use that.

Comment: How did you create the HPROF file in the first place?

Comment: @CommonsWare In Eclipse, Open Perspective > DDMS, in the devices view i clicked "Dump HPROF File" and then i got the file above automatically open in eclipse

Comment: Are you trying to use the standalone MAT, or the MAT that is an Eclipse plugin?

Comment: @CommonsWare I downloaded the standalone from the Eclipse website. If it can work within eclipse though i would like to know how to do that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "Open in Eclipse" option will only work if you are using the MAT Eclipse plugin. The [MAT Downloads page](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php) shows the "Update Site" link, which you can add to Eclipse via Help > Install New Software > Add.

Comment: it worked in my computer with independent MAT maybe someone at eclipse upgraded that functionality.

Comment: I had the same problem as OP and had the independent MAT. I had no idea there was a plugin. The tutorials I tried to follow didn't specify.

Answer (score 7):

You can use **HPROF Converter** tool provided in android sdk.

The **hprof-conv** tool converts the HPROF file that is generated by the Android SDK tools to a standard format so you can view the file in a profiling tool of your choice.

```
hprof-conv <infile> <outfile>
```

More at [HPROF Converter](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hprof-conv.html)

After converting file opens without any Issue.

Answer (score 0):

- You can still use a separated MAT (which I figured out is the right
  thing to do because the guy who develop this system does it that way
  and he seems to know it's smarter way to separate concerns)
- You can do that. You have to copy that file to a non temporary
  directory (desktop or something like that) and open that like you
  would a converted file.
- You save this file and than open it in the MAT Eclipse.
- It seems like the the DDMS save to disk saves the regular .hprof file
  and the other version save to file save an encoded adt version at
  least on my machine.

  for more information on this approach watch this video 
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk